# Randomise (rearrange) dataframe rows in R in alternating manner using a 2 level factor column variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to randomize my data collection. I am going to observe 10 animals (`baboon_list`) and each animal gets 4 sessions (2 am and 2 pm). So in total there are 40 sessions.

```
baboon_list=rep(c("Hound","Sunflower","Nick","Pompom",
                  "CrookedTail","Hugger","R","Chris","Puncture","Brown"),each=4)

session_vec=rep(c("AM","PM"),each=1,times=20)

sampling=data.frame(baboon_list,session_vec)

randomized_sampling=sampling[sample(nrow(sampling)),]
```

I wish to randomize the way I observe them. I created a randomized data frame but I want it to be listed with alternating am and pm sessions. That is, the rows should be randomized but arranged in alternating am and pm sessions. How do I do that?
For now, I randomized the `baboon_list` vector before combining it with `session_vec` into a data frame which solved my purpose.

```
data.frame(sample(baboon_list),session_vec)
```

How about if I am given such a dataframe and I have to rearrange it? Should I deconstruct that data frame and reconstruct using my method?
Sorry if this is a trivial question, I am new to R and statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with your "sorted" `sampling` dataframe, you could do something like the following. For each baboon, select 4 random row (`rr`) positions from the remaining rows and label those baboon rows with the random row value. Then remove the row positions from the available rows (`! rows %in% rr`) and repeat with the next baboon.

```
baboons = levels(sampling$baboon_list)
rows = 1:nrow(sampling)
d = data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(baboons)) {
  n = nrow(sampling[baboon_list=='R',])
  rr = sort(sample(rows,n))   # 4 random row positions
  d = rbind(d,
            data.frame(sampling[baboon_list==baboons[i],], rr) )
  rows = rows[! rows %in% rr]  # remove the 4 row positions
}
subset(d, baboon_list=='Brown')

   baboon_list session_vec rr
37       Brown          AM  2
38       Brown          PM  6
39       Brown          AM 23
40       Brown          PM 30
```

Comment: wow, thanks I would not have been able to come up with that with my current proficiency in R :D @pcantalupo

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is using the function `interleave` from the gdata package. First you randomise your data frame, and then interweave the rows in alternating order:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- sampling[sample(nrow(sampling), 40), ]
library(gdata)
interleave(df[df$session_vec=="AM",], df[df$session_vec=="PM",])
```

Output:

```
   baboon_list session_vec
11        Nick          AM
22      Hugger          PM
15      Pompom          AM
34    Puncture          PM
33    Puncture          AM
8    Sunflower          PM
21      Hugger          AM
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mpalanco !! a lot in deed :)