# Randomly alternate between rows based on a 3 level variable in a df

Tags: r, row, shuffle

**What I want**

I want to randomly shuffle the rows of a df (44 rows) based on the column "condition" which has 3 levels with different lengths. Level 1 (neutral) has 11 rows, Level 2 (fem) has 11 rows, Level 3 (filler) has 22 rows.

I want to alternate the df so that the first row contains Level 3 (filler) > Level 1 (neutral) > Level 3 (filler) > Level 2 (fem), and so on.

**My df structure**

```
Rows: 44
Columns: 11
$ display              <chr> "experimental_eye_tracking", "experimental_eye_tracking", "experimental_eye_tracking"…
$ ANSWER               <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N…
$ TopLeft              <chr> "1_row-1-column-1.png", "2_row-1-column-1.png", "3_row-1-column-1.png", "4_row-1-colu…
$ BottomLeft           <chr> "1_row-1-column-2.png", "2_row-1-column-2.png", "3_row-1-column-2.png", "4_row-1-colu…
$ TopRight             <chr> "1_row-2-column-1.png", "2_row-2-column-1.png", "3_row-2-column-1.png", "4_row-2-colu…
$ BottomRight          <chr> "1_row-2-column-2.png", "2_row-2-column-2.png", "3_row-2-column-2.png", "4_row-2-colu…
$ audio                <chr> "بعد الصيف تم انتخاب الرئيسة.mp3", "بعد الصباح تم إخراج الأم.mp3", "في المساء تم تنوي…
$ item_type            <chr> "experimental", "experimental", "experimental", "experimental", "experimental", "expe…
$ condition            <chr> "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral…
$ comprehension_Q      <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N…
```

**The distribution of the 3-level variable**

```
 [1] "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral"
[12] "fem"     "fem"     "fem"     "fem"     "fem"     "fem"     "fem"     "fem"     "fem"     "fem"     "fem"    
[23] "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler" 
[34] "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"  "filler"
```

**What I did**

I used this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289673/17746590), but I got the error message that "Arguments have differening numbers of rows"

**What I expect**

I want the df to have the following order

```
Rows: 10
Columns: 2
$ condition <chr> "filler", "neutral", "filler", "fem", "filler", "neutral", "filler", "fem", "filler", "neutral"
$ trial     <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

---

## Data in `dput` format

```
c("neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "fem", 
"fem", "fem", "fem", "fem", "fem", "fem", "fem", "fem", "fem", 
"fem", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", 
"filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", 
"filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", "filler", 
"filler", "filler")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the size of each group for sure, it is just a matter of calculating the indices efficiently and *rearranging* the `data.frame` based on those.

```
## generate sample data with group sizes N, N and 2N
N = 11
df = data.frame(
  condition = c(
    rep('neutral', N),
    rep('fem', N),
    rep('filler', 2*N)
  )
)

## calculate indices
ids = c(2*N, 0, 3*N, N) + rep(1:N, each = 4)

## rearrange data.frame using indices
df_rearranged = df[ids,]
```

If you actually wanted to introduce some randomness ("*randomly* shuffle"), you would need a different approach.

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering and for suggesting such a concise code/approach. I'll try it and let you if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

here is a data.table approch

**sample data**

```
set.seed(123)
library(data.table)
mydata <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10), rep(3,20)))
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, value := paste0(id, "_", rowid(id))]

    id value
 1:  1   1_1
 2:  1   1_2
 3:  1   1_3
 4:  1   1_4
 5:  1   1_5
 6:  1   1_6
 7:  1   1_7
 8:  1   1_8
 9:  1   1_9
10:  1  1_10
11:  2   2_1
12:  2   2_2
13:  2   2_3
14:  2   2_4
15:  2   2_5
16:  2   2_6
17:  2   2_7
18:  2   2_8
19:  2   2_9
20:  2  2_10
21:  3   3_1
22:  3   3_2
23:  3   3_3
24:  3   3_4
25:  3   3_5
26:  3   3_6
27:  3   3_7
28:  3   3_8
29:  3   3_9
30:  3  3_10
31:  3  3_11
32:  3  3_12
33:  3  3_13
34:  3  3_14
35:  3  3_15
36:  3  3_16
37:  3  3_17
38:  3  3_18
39:  3  3_19
40:  3  3_20
    id value
```

**code**

```
#add rowid's by group
mydata[, rowid := rowid(id)][]
# create a dummy data.table with the shuffled order of id's
desired <- data.table(id = rep_len(c(1,3,2,3), length.out = nrow(mydata)))
desired[, rowid := rowid(id)]
# now we can join
desired[mydata, value := i.value, on = .(id, rowid)]
# drop the rowid
desired[, rowid := NULL]
```

**output**

```
    id value
 1:  1   1_1
 2:  3   3_1
 3:  2   2_1
 4:  3   3_2
 5:  1   1_2
 6:  3   3_3
 7:  2   2_2
 8:  3   3_4
 9:  1   1_3
10:  3   3_5
11:  2   2_3
12:  3   3_6
13:  1   1_4
14:  3   3_7
15:  2   2_4
16:  3   3_8
17:  1   1_5
18:  3   3_9
19:  2   2_5
20:  3  3_10
21:  1   1_6
22:  3  3_11
23:  2   2_6
24:  3  3_12
25:  1   1_7
26:  3  3_13
27:  2   2_7
28:  3  3_14
29:  1   1_8
30:  3  3_15
31:  2   2_8
32:  3  3_16
33:  1   1_9
34:  3  3_17
35:  2   2_9
36:  3  3_18
37:  1  1_10
38:  3  3_19
39:  2  2_10
40:  3  3_20
    id value
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just had this issue while running the code: "Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object 'i.value' not found". What should I replace "i.value" with? Thank you for your help

Comment: `i.value` is the value column in `i` (data.table syntax). In the code above, `i` is the data.table `mydata`. So basically, what `value := i.value` does, is: update a `value`-column in `desired`, baed on the corresponding `value` in `mydata`. I understand that data.table syntax is a bit hard to read when not familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the code. I replaced "value" and "i.value" with the corresponding "condition" column in my df. It worked so well!! Many thanks, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df[c(matrix(setDT(df)[, sample(.I), condition][[2]], 4, byrow = 1)[c(4, 1, 3:2),]),]
```

Starting with:

```
df <- data.frame(
    condition = rep.int(c("neutral", "fem", "filler"), c(11, 11, 22)),
    other_columns = 1:44
  )
```

Results in:

```
#>     condition other_columns
#>  1:    filler            24
#>  2:   neutral             9
#>  3:    filler            35
#>  4:       fem            17
#>  5:    filler            31
#>  6:   neutral             4
#>  7:    filler            43
#>  8:       fem            14
#>  9:    filler            37
#> 10:   neutral             7
#> 11:    filler            30
#> 12:       fem            13
#> 13:    filler            27
#> 14:   neutral             1
#> 15:    filler            42
#> 16:       fem            19
#> 17:    filler            40
#> 18:   neutral            10
#> 19:    filler            29
#> 20:       fem            21
#> 21:    filler            36
#> 22:   neutral             6
#> 23:    filler            33
#> 24:       fem            18
#> 25:    filler            34
#> 26:   neutral             8
#> 27:    filler            41
#> 28:       fem            22
#> 29:    filler            38
#> 30:   neutral             3
#> 31:    filler            23
#> 32:       fem            16
#> 33:    filler            26
#> 34:   neutral             2
#> 35:    filler            25
#> 36:       fem            20
#> 37:    filler            39
#> 38:   neutral             5
#> 39:    filler            28
#> 40:       fem            12
#> 41:    filler            32
#> 42:   neutral            11
#> 43:    filler            44
#> 44:       fem            15
#>     condition other_columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a function that shuffles the data by levels of `condition`, puts all together alternating the levels as required and returns an index into the rows of the input data.frame. Then use the index to order the data.frame.

```r
fun <- function(data) {
  x <- data$condition
  x <- factor(x, levels = c("filler", "neutral", "fem"))
  i <- ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN = sample)
  sp <- split(i, x)
  sp$filler2 <- sp$filler[(length(sp$neutral) + 1L):length(sp$filler)]
  sp$filler <- sp$filler[1:length(sp$neutral)]
  sp <- sp[c(1:2, 4, 3)]
  sp |> as.data.frame() |> t() |> c()
}

# made up data
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = sprintf("row %0d", seq_along(x)),
  condition = x
)

i <- fun(df1)
df1[i, ]
#>        id condition
#> 25 row 25    filler
#> 9   row 9   neutral
#> 32 row 32    filler
#> 16 row 16       fem
#> 24 row 24    filler
#> 2   row 2   neutral
#> 43 row 43    filler
#> 12 row 12       fem
#> 30 row 30    filler
#> 6   row 6   neutral
#> 31 row 31    filler
#> 22 row 22       fem
#> 40 row 40    filler
#> 11 row 11   neutral
#> 44 row 44    filler
#> 21 row 21       fem
#> 26 row 26    filler
#> 7   row 7   neutral
#> 38 row 38    filler
#> 13 row 13       fem
#> 37 row 37    filler
#> 4   row 4   neutral
#> 35 row 35    filler
#> 20 row 20       fem
#> 36 row 36    filler
#> 10 row 10   neutral
#> 28 row 28    filler
#> 18 row 18       fem
#> 33 row 33    filler
#> 1   row 1   neutral
#> 34 row 34    filler
#> 14 row 14       fem
#> 42 row 42    filler
#> 8   row 8   neutral
#> 27 row 27    filler
#> 19 row 19       fem
#> 29 row 29    filler
#> 5   row 5   neutral
#> 41 row 41    filler
#> 15 row 15       fem
#> 39 row 39    filler
#> 3   row 3   neutral
#> 23 row 23    filler
#> 17 row 17       fem
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks! When I ran the function, I got a vector of re-ordered row numbers e.g.,  [1] 44  1 29 14 36 11 26 13 43  4 31 20 40 ....etc. Could you please explain how to incorporate that into the original df to shuffle the rows?

Comment: Okay, this is what I did to add the resulting vector of re-ordered rows into my df. I ran the function: <order_vector <- fun(pilot_items)>. Then, I added a column for the order_vector to the df: <pilot_items$order_vector <- order_vector>. Finally, I re-ordered the rows based on the "order_vector": <pilot_items_2 <- pilot_items[order(pilot_items$order_vector), ]>. However, the results were not as expected. In some rows, I got non-wanted orders such as filler > fem > fem > filler.

Comment: @Alaa If you want to reorder the data.frame, try `new_pilot_items <- pilot_items[order_vector, ]`.  new df is now in the required order.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- data.frame(
  a = 1:44,
  condition = c(rep("neutral", 11), rep("fem", 11), rep("filler", 22))
)

library(data.table)
setDT(x)

# make a factor first with levels
x[, condition := factor(condition, levels = c("filler", "neutral", "fem"))]

# sample by group and order randomly (note order of groups remains the same)
x[, i := sample(1:.N, .N, replace = F), condition]
setorder(x, condition, i)

# adapted from @rellach answer
x[c(0, 2, 1, 3)*(.N/4) + rep(1:(.N/4), each = 4), ]


#     a condition
# 1: 29    filler
# 2:  1   neutral
# 3: 37    filler
# 4: 14       fem
# 5: 30    filler
# 6: 11   neutral
# 7: 34    filler
# 8: 20       fem
# 9: 36    filler
# 10:  6   neutral
# 11: 32    filler
# 12: 21       fem
# 13: 43    filler
# 14:  4   neutral
# 15: 39    filler
# 16: 18       fem
# 17: 42    filler
# 18:  9   neutral
# 19: 44    filler
# 20: 15       fem
```